# Drawing line graph using Quartz?

Tags: ios, ios6, quartz-graphics

I am trying to make a simple graph for the ipad. I need to plot sin(x), cos(x) and tan(x) functions using QUARTZ. I know how to make the grid and the lines, but have no idea how to start with this. Any help is appreciated.

Please note I am not interested in core plot and other frameworks so please don't offer this as an answer.

Comment: Core Plot doesn't draw function graphs anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: you decide what resolution/precision you want, then you split the domain of the functions into intervals according to that, you calculate the values of the function in each interval and you connect those with a straight line:

```
// Within a subclass of UIView
- (void)drawFunction:(double (*)(double))fn from:(double)x1 to:(double)x2
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat comps[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(ctx, comps);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0);

    const double dx = 0.01; // precision
    double scale_x = self.bounds.size.width / (x2 - x1);
    double off_x = 0.0;
    double scale_y = scale_x;
    double off_y = self.bounds.size.height / 2;

    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, x1 * scale_x - off_x, off_y - fn(x1) * scale_y);

    for (double x = x1 + dx; x <= x2; x += dx) {
        double y = fn(x);
        CGFloat xp = x * scale_x - off_x;
        CGFloat yp = off_y - y * scale_y;
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, xp, yp);
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```

Call this from `- drawRect:`:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    [self drawFunction:sin from:0.0 to: 2 * M_PI];
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but this doesn't draw anything or am I missing something

Comment: @JamesDouglas (I was almost sure you was going to come back with "hey this is not working!!!!!") Surely. Pay attention to sizes, limits, set the stroke color and line width, maybe call `CGContextStrokePath()` at the end, etc. Read up that in the documentation of `CGContexRef`.

Comment: Ok will play with that. Lol

Comment: @JamesDouglas Make some effort yourself, please. I've slightly updated the code, check it now.

Comment: I managed to get a line but it's just curved line rather than a wave any suggestions?

Comment: @JamesDouglas It's offset by some value either in the X or Y direction, change that. Mess around with the code, apply logic and common sense, etc.